# How to solve problems with the installation of Virtual-Box?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I installed Virtual-Box in Ubuntu 18.04 from the "ubuntu software" store
My laptop is an Asus, 8GB RAM and for now it works well.
I am trying to install Kaly Linux in Virtual-Box with the following configuration:
4 GB RAM, 16 GB hard drive. And the partitions created a swap of 512 MG, and the rest I leave it for `root`.

When the installation starts, the laptop is completely blocked, it freezes and I need to turn off the button, to restart it again.

This has happened to me the 4 times I've tried this morning, in the afternoon I'm trying to find a question here like mine, without success.

Any idea why this happens?

Would it be better to install from the terminal to avoid errors?
The image I downloaded from Kaly was the one I showed in the capture.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enabled virtualization in your BIOS settings? If not try doing that.

[Intel page about how to do this](https://www.intel.pl/content/www/pl/pl/support/articles/000007139/server-products.html)

Some time ago I had similar issue and it solved it.

Comment: I will study your advice @Tomek Piechocki, but I was running kaly on this same laptop when it was windows,
Thank you.

Comment: Just check to be sure. It's just one of many possibilites, but it's general for every virtual machine. Good luck

Comment: Good, I have not been able to answer so far. Yes, I have it enabled.
Thanks for the interest @TomekPiechocki